# how to interpret pclose() status when popen() fails?

Tags: c, linux, popen, busybox

My application running on embedded linux (busybox) tries to execute a script via `popen(cmd, "r")`.
`cmd = "sh /tmp/DF1_05/update.sh DF1_05"`

I can execute this script without problem launching it by hand from sh, but it fails when it's launched by the application.
The first lines of `update.sh` script are:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Starting update script"
....
```

I cannot even see the `echo` ouput.

My application's code is:

```
sprintf(cmd,"sh /tmp/%s/update.sh %s",version_ihm_usb,version_ihm_usb);
printf("Executing script %s\n", cmd);
pipe_cmd = popen(cmd,"r");
if (pipe_cmd != NULL) {
    int ret = pclose(pipe_cmd);
    printf("pclose returned %d:%d,%d\n", ret, WIFEXITED(ret), WEXITSTATUS(ret));
    return 0;
} else {
    printf("Error executing script : %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

The application output is:

```
Executing script sh /tmp/DF1_05/update.sh DF1_05
pclose returned 36096:1,141
```

So according to [popen man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html), `pclose` outputs a status similar to what [wait4](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html) outputs and as `WIFEXITED(ret)` is true, `WEXITSTATUS(ret)` is the output status of the child .......
Ok but after that it's a treasure hunt for me and in fact, I cannot interpret what code `141` is.

Does anyone have more precise info?

Comment: Run `sh /tmp/%s/update.sh %s` manually in an interactive shell and check `echo $?` after it finishes.

Comment: You do not see the `echo` because you have to read it from the `pipe_cmd` file.  You can debug your script by placing a `set -x` into it (or call it as `sh -x /tmp/...`); output appears on stderr in this case

Comment: ok, thanks to both of you, managing outputs in a better way helped me to find the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I cannot interpret what code 141 is.

From [man popen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) emphasis mine:

> The popen() function opens a process by creating a pipe, forking, and **invoking the shell**.

From [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Exit-Status), which is a common convention:

> When a command terminates on a fatal signal whose number is N, Bash uses the value 128+N as the exit status.

From [man signal](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html):

```
   Signal        x86/ARM     Alpha/   MIPS   PARISC   Notes
               most others   SPARC
   ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   SIGHUP           1           1       1       1
   .... other signals ....
   SIGPIPE         13          13      13      13
```

The process was terminated by `SIGPIPE`. `SIGPIPE` is 13 on your system. So your  shell returned the exit status as `128 + 13 = 141`.

Answer (score 3):

Check `WIFSIGNALED(ret)` and `WTERMSIG(ret)`. You may find that the child was terminated by a SIGPIPE.

Also, `pclose` is not likely failing here, but I would check its return value before passing that to the wait macros. If `pclose` returns < 0, log an error.